# Bad mask for loopback interface

Tags: routing, bgp

I am trying to implement BGP  session. I was given this table.

[image]

When  I try to configure loopbacks the first loopback works in the proper way

```
R1(config)#interface loopback 0
R1(config-if)#ip
*Mar  1 00:45:15.839: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback0, changed state to up
R1(config-if)#ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
```

But when i try to configure loopback 1 that's the error I get

```
> R1(config)#interface loopback 1
> R1(config-if)#ip address 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0
> Bad mask /24 for address 192.168.11.0
```

I don't know if i understand it in the proper way. Or maybe the table is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an IP address where the host part is all zeros (=network address) or all ones (=directed broadcast address). If you use any other address from 192.168.11.1/24 to 192.168.11.254/24 it'll work.

Comment: With a /32 mask

Comment: @BenjaminDale, or with a `/31` address`

Comment: `/31`?  interesting - what is the application?

Comment: @BenjaminDale /31 is used for numbered point-to-point links - essentially like /30 but with only half the address consumption.

Comment: Sorry - I get what a /31 is - just wondering the application of putting a non /32 mask on a loopback interface would be?